# How to make a responsive play button in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I was able to make a play button but I could not able to make it responsive. If you can please tell me the code it would be helpful. Also I need to understand it as I am a beginner flutter user.

Comment: Please share with us your code for the play button. Then people will be able to help you.

Answer (score 4):

I think you should first learn about stateful widgets and basic flutter components first.

Introduction to widgets : https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/widgets-intro

Flutter Basic Widgets : https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/widgets

You can start from below code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MusicPlayer extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MusicPlayerState createState() => _MusicPlayerState();
}

class _MusicPlayerState extends State<MusicPlayer> {
  var isPlaying = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Music Player"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: IconButton(
            icon: isPlaying
                ? Icon(
                    Icons.pause_circle_outline,
                    size: 40.0,
                  )
                : Icon(Icons.play_circle_outline, size: 40.0),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                isPlaying = !isPlaying;
              });
            }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This will help you get started for your project.